# MongoDB - Get the first matching document multiple times - Which is better?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregate

Imagine a collection looks like this:

```
{
  created_at: Date,
  color: string, // 'blue' | 'red' | 'yellow'
}
```

I have thousands or millions of documents in a collection with random created_at date-times and different colors.
Now I want to have the latest created document for color 'blue' AND the latest created document for color 'red'.

Which approach is best? (Feel free to suggest another one)

**A) Multiple queries in parallel**

```
const latest = await Promise.all([
   collection.findOne({ color: 'blue' }, { sort: { created_at: -1 } }),
   collection.findOne({ color: 'red' }, { sort: { created_at: -1 } }),
]);
```

**B) One aggregate query - group**

```
const latest = await collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { color: { $in: ['blue', 'red'] } } },
  { $sort: { created_at: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$color",
      latest: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
]).toArray();
```

**C) One aggregate query - facet**

```
const latest = await collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { color: { $in: ['blue', 'red'] } } },
  { $sort: { created_at: -1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      blue: [
        { $match: { color: 'blue' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      red: [
        { $match: { color: 'red' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
    }
  },
]).toArray();
```

Which one is the best for performance? What if I want to do this for more than 2 colors?

Sidequestion: I actually wonder about this a lot for $facet operations. Since $facet cannot use indices, it seems better to just do multiple queries in parallel in some situations. If you have lots of documents per group (in this case 'color'), using an index seems useful. So I guess option C is not very good. For option B, I wonder if MongoDB first needs to get all documents that match the generic condition, sort all of them, group all of them, to then only take the first...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

None of your solutions use index (which I guess is because you haven't created it).

Create the following index:

`{ color: 1, created_at: -1  }`

Then you can run explain plan on your queries and see how they behave.

I "think" the first one would be fastest.

Comment: Thanks @Yahya. I would of course create the needed indices depending on the chosen approach. For $facet it doesn't matter because it will never use any index.
I can create this situation and do some testing yes, but I'm curious about the intuitive expectations. My actual situation is more complicated and a simplified test might not result in the right conclusion.

Extra question: Would it be better to have index `{ color: 1, created_at: -1  }` or `{ created_at: -1, color: 1  }` ?

Comment: `{ color: 1, created_at: -1  }` is better in your case, as you are putting equality first and then range. Indexes in MongoDB are B+ trees. So putting equality first makes sense.

Comment: Hi @Yahya, thanks for your help. I did some testing and posted the results in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems options A is the best, at least in the situation I tested.

I did a performance test as follows:

I created a collection with 3.000.000 documents with 2 fields:

- `created_at`: Random Date between 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z & 2030-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
- `color`: Random string, 31 different options

I did a query to get the latest created document for each of 17 different colors.

**Results**

|  | No index | { color: 1, created_at: -1 } | { created_at: -1, color: 1 } |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1) One FindOne (shell) | 70 ms | 60 ms | 60 ms |
| A2) FindOnes in parallel (JS) | 21944 ms | 543 ms | 572 ms |
| B) Aggregate - Group - First | QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed | 9120 ms | 10200 ms |
| C) Aggregate - Facet | QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed | 3860 ms | 4770 ms |

Option A1 is the fastest, but that's just for one color (I couldn't do it in parallel via the shell). So the real winner is option A2! Also note that A2 is done via a locally run JS-script that connects to external DB. It still is way faster than the other options that are done via the shell directly.

I checked the impact of doing 5 findOnes in parallel instead of 17:

A3) FindOnes in parallel (JS) | 6656 ms | 334 ms | 339 ms

This is significantly faster. I suspect that if you need way more than 17 cases, other options might be better. It isn't relevant for my needs, so I didn't test this.

---

For completeness, the exact queries:

A1)

```
db.getCollection('colors').findOne({ color: 'Ivory' }, { sort: { created_at: -1 } })
```

A2)

```
const latest = await Promise.all(colors.map((c) => mongodb.collection('colors').findOne({ color: c }, { sort: { created_at: -1 } })));
```

B)

```
db.getCollection('colors').aggregate([
  { $match: { color: { $in: [
    'Ivory',
    'Teal',
    'Silver',
    'Purple',
    'Navy blue',
    'Pea green',
    'Gray',
    'Orange',
    'Maroon',
    'Charcoal',
    'Aquamarine',
    'Coral',
    'Fuchsia',
    'Wheat',
    'Lime',
    'Crimson',
    'Khaki'
  ] } } },
  { $sort: { created_at: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$color",
      latest: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
]);
```

C)

```
db.getCollection('colors').aggregate([
  { $match: { color: { $in: [
    'Ivory',
    'Teal',
    'Silver',
    'Purple',
    'Navy blue',
    'Pea green',
    'Gray',
    'Orange',
    'Maroon',
    'Charcoal',
    'Aquamarine',
    'Coral',
    'Fuchsia',
    'Wheat',
    'Lime',
    'Crimson',
    'Khaki'
  ] } } },
  { $sort: { created_at: -1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      Ivory: [
        { $match: { color: 'Ivory' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Teal: [
        { $match: { color: 'Teal' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Silver: [
        { $match: { color: 'Silver' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Purple: [
        { $match: { color: 'Purple' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Navyblue: [
        { $match: { color: 'Navy blue' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Peagreen: [
        { $match: { color: 'Pea green' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Gray: [
        { $match: { color: 'Gray' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Orange: [
        { $match: { color: 'Orange' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Maroon: [
        { $match: { color: 'Maroon' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Charcoal: [
        { $match: { color: 'Charcoal' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Aquamarine: [
        { $match: { color: 'Aquamarine' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Coral: [
        { $match: { color: 'Coral' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Fuchsia: [
        { $match: { color: 'Fuchsia' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Wheat: [
        { $match: { color: 'Wheat' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Lime: [
        { $match: { color: 'Lime' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Crimson: [
        { $match: { color: 'Crimson' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      Khaki: [
        { $match: { color: 'Khaki' } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
    }
  },
]);
```